# How to manage and patch enterprise docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-ee

How do organizations handle patching of internal Docker images?  I'm not able to find any documentation on this.

I want to make sure that my approach aligns with the Docker best practices. To sum up, this is my strategy:

1. Create an image hierarchy using the Centos7 image as the base image to build the following images:

   ```
   tomcat
   python
   java
   jboss
   apache
   ```
2. Include a `yum update -y` in the Centos7 Dockerfile and release monthly images with a specific tag. ie:

   ```
   internal-registry.example/admin/centos7:oct2020
   ```
3. Dockerfiles for the child images will also be updated to pull from the newest monthly image and tag them as well.  ie: tomcat Dockerfile.

   ```
   FROM internal-registry.example/admin/centos7:nov2020
   ```
4. Push images to the registry and perform image scanning.
5. Notify development teams every month to build images with the new tag.

Is there a better way to handle patches?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot patch docker images. Do you mean updating your stack on a monthly basis?

Comment: How would CVE detected by image scans be resolved?